# How to reboot Ubuntu Server by command? Error 'Failed to reboot: Invalid argument. System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1)'

Tags: boot, reboot

I install Ubuntu on Windows 10 via Microsoft Store!
and I can't reboot it
I try Google and error:

```
root@kami.vn:~# sudo reboot now
Failed to write reboot parameter file: No such file or directory
root@kami.vn:~# sudo reboot -f
Rebooting.
Failed to reboot: Invalid argument
root@kami.vn:~# sudo reboot
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to talk to init daemon.
root@kami.vn:~# sudo reboot -h
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to talk to init daemon.
root@kami.vn:~# sudo reboot -h now
Failed to write reboot parameter file: No such file or directory
root@kami.vn:~# sudo shutdown -r now
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to talk to init daemon.
root@kami.vn:~# sudo shutdown -r -H +0
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to talk to init daemon.
root@kami.vn:~# sudo systemctl reboot
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
root@kami.vn:~#
```

How to reboot it? Thanks

I got the answer:

wslreboot
wsl --shutdown

Comment: I think you'll find you're using an Ubuntu flavour of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about. If you want to reboot the computer do that as normal from within Windows. If you want a new instance of WSL then close the window and re-open in the same way you did before; you'll have a fresh "boot" of a system to work on. You can [restart the service that runs WSL](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-reboot-wsl-windows-subsystem-linux-in-windows-10.html), eg in PowerShell do `Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service`.

Comment: FYI "#" at the prompt in your pasted text shows you're superuser and don't need to use `sudo` (superuser-do, or do this as super user).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already logged in as super user and you don't need `sudo` before your command. Anyway, please try this command and see if it works:

```
#/sbin/reboot
```

Or

```
#/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Comment: root@kami.vn:~# #/sbin/reboot
root@kami.vn:~# /sbin/reboot
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to talk to init daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo service redis-server start`

Your version of WSL may not use systemd.  The above command is used to restart the server.

Comment: root@kami.vn:~# sudo service redis-server start
redis-server: unrecognized service

Comment: You might just have to use the WSL command line in Windows https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference